# Create dictionary from dict and list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I have a dictionary :

```
dicocategory = {}
dicocategory["a"] = ["crapow", "Killian", "pauk", "victor"]
dicocategory["b"] = ["graton", "fred"]
dicocategory["c"] = ["babar", "poca", "german", "Georges", "nowak"]
dicocategory["d"] = ["crado", "cradi", "hibou", "distopia", "fiboul"]
dicocategory["e"] = ["makenkosapo"]
```

and a list :

```
my_list = ['makenkosapo', 'Killian', 'Georges', 'poca', 'nowak']
```

I want to create a new dictionary with my dicocategory's keys as new keys and items of my list as values.
To get the keys of my new dict (removing duplicate content and adapted to my list) I made :

```
def tablemain(my_list ):
    tableheaders = list()
    for value in my_list:
        tableheaders.append([k for k, v in dicocategory.items() if value in v])
    convertlist = [j for i in tableheaders for j in i]
    headerstablefinal = list(set(convertlist))   
    return headerstablefinal
```

giving me:

```
['e', 'a', 'c']
```

My problem is: I don't know how to put the items of my list in the corresponding keys.

EDIT : 
Bellow an output of what I want

```
{"a" : ['Killian'], 'c' : ['Georges', 'poca', 'nowak'], 'e' : ['makenkosapo']}
```

The list my_list can change, so I want something that can create a new dictionary doesn't matter the list.
If my new list is :

```
my_list = ['crapow', 'german', 'pauk']
```

My output will be :

```
{'a':['crapow', 'pauk'], 'c':['german']}
```

Do you have any idea?
Thank you

Comment: This is quite confused. It's not clear what you want the final result to be. Moreover, based on your initial dictionary, you cannot make a DataFrame from this as the lists have differing lengths.

Comment: It wasn't clear. I edited it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a couple of dictionary comprehensions. Calculate the intersection in the first, and in the second remove instances where the intersection is empty:

```
my_set = set(my_list)

# calculate intersection
res = {k: set(v) & my_set for k, v in dicocategory.items()}

# remove zero intersection values
res = {k: v for k, v in res.items() if v}

print(res)

{'a': {'Killian'},
 'c': {'Georges', 'nowak', 'poca'},
 'e': {'makenkosapo'}}
```

More efficiently, you can use a generator expression to avoid an intermediary dictionary:

```
# generate intersection
gen = ((k, set(v) & my_set) for k, v in dicocategory.items())

# remove zero intersection values
res = {k: v for k, v in gen if v}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a dictionary containing only keys with values that match your list like this:

```
{k:v for k,v in dicocategory.items() if set(v).intersection(set(my_list))}
```

You won't be able to put that directly into a DataFrame though as the lists differ in length.